# Elasticsearch Watcher : How to alert if data is out of sync

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-watcher

I want to put a watcher alert for my index. My data looks like this

```
id:1,val:popo
id:2,val:lplp
id:3,val:gjj
id:4,val:asd
```

basically, the ids need to be in a sequence. Now if i receive something like this

```
id:1,val:popo
id:2,val:lplp
id:4,val:gjj
id:5,val:asd
```

then, the record with `id:3` did not arrive. If something like this happens, then i want to receive an alert. Is it possible to do something like this with watcher? I just need to check if the id of the current record is 1 more than the most recent record received.

Comment: And what if you index 100 documents per second? This means you will do 100 Watcher triggers and 100 search queries per second? It doesn't sound right.

Comment: can i run this watch like every hour? i check the documents indexed in the last hour and then alert

Comment: You can run it every hour, of course. And then what query will you use to find the "missing" links? And only for the "new" documents since the last check.

Comment: lets say i have a timestamp associated with each record. then every hour i can run a range query where the timestamp falls within the past hour. for those documents is it possible for me to check if the ids are in sequence?

Comment: It should be possible with a Groovy script. But I can't estimate the performance of this query.

Comment: hmm, that might be something worth looking into. where can i learn more about groovy scripts with respect to elastic?